# send orderform ajax to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i need to send an order row by ajax to php...but have lack about this...anyone can help me?
(it a very simple order form with populating from xml file and add a select items with a simple menù )

```
//Retrieve XML document and loop for each item
    jQuery(function($) { //just like $(document).ready()
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/menu.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            error: function() {
                $("<p>Error loading XML file...</p>")
                .replaceAll("#order_form")
            },
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find("item").each(fWriteXML); //must call function as var
            }
        });
    });

    //Populate drop-down box with XML contents
    var fWriteXML = function writeXML() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var cost = $(this).attr("cost");
        var item = $(this).text();
        $("#select_item")
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .val(id) //same as .attr("value", id))
            .html(item)
            .attr("title", cost));
    };

    //Add selected item to order
    $(function() {
        $("#add_btn").click(function() {
            var order_item_selected_quantity = $("#select_quantity").val()
            var selected_item = $("#select_item option:selected");
            var order_item_selected_id = selected_item.val();
            var order_item_selected_name = selected_item.text();
            var order_item_selected_cost = selected_item.attr("title");

            var pattern = new RegExp("^[1-9][0-9]?$"); //Select between 1-99 items
            //Do not proceed if input is incorrect
            if (pattern.test(order_item_selected_quantity) &&
                order_item_selected_cost != "") {

                //Calculate subtotal
                var order_item_selected_subtotal =
                    parseFloat(order_item_selected_cost) *
                    parseInt(order_item_selected_quantity);

                $("<tr class='order_row'></tr>").html("<td>"
                    + order_item_selected_quantity + "</td><td>"
                    + order_item_selected_id + "</td><td class='order_item_name'>"
                    + order_item_selected_name + "</td><td class='order_item_cost'>"
                    + order_item_selected_cost + "</td><td class='order_item_subtotal'>"
                    + order_item_selected_subtotal + "</td><td>"
                    + "<input type='button' value='elimina' /></td>")
                        .appendTo("#order_cart").hide();

                $("#order_cart tr.order_row:last").fadeIn("medium", function() {
                    orderTotal(); //Callback once animation is complete
                });

                //Format new order item values to currency
                $("#order_cart td.order_item_cost:last").formatCurrency();
                $("#order_cart td.order_item_subtotal:last").formatCurrency();

                clickRemove();
                clearForm();
            }
        });
    });

    //Bind a click event to the correct remove button
    function clickRemove() {
        $("#order_cart tr.order_row:last input").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().children().fadeOut("fast", function() {
                $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function() {   //the row (tr)
                    $(this).remove();   //the row (tr)
                    orderTotal();
                });
            });
        });
    };

    //Clear order input form and re-focus cursor
    function clearForm() {
        $("#select_quantity").val("");
        $("#select_item option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
        $("#select_quantity").focus();
    };

    //Calculate new order total
    function orderTotal() {
        var order_total = 0;
        $("#order_cart td.order_item_subtotal").each(function() {
            var amount = ($(this).html()).replace("€", "");
            order_total += parseFloat(amount);
        });

        $("#order_total").text(order_total).formatCurrency();

        //Create alternating colored rows in order table
        $("#order_cart tr.order_row:odd").css("background-color", "#FF0");
        $("#order_cart tr.order_row:even").css("background-color", "#FFF");
    };

    //Pretend to place order if it contains items
    $(function() {
        $("#order_btn").click(function() {


            /* MISSING PART */

        alert("Order placed...");


        });
    });
```

thx a lot

mod.
and this html

```
<table id="select">
    <caption>
        Menu</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Qnt.:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="select_quantity" type="text" />&nbsp;(*1-99)
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="select_item">
                <option selected="selected">Seleziona un prodotto...</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="add_btn" type="button" value="Aggiungi" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />

<br />

<table id="order_cart" >

    <caption>
        Ordine</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Qnt.
            </th>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Descrizione
            </th>
            <th>
                Prezzo
            </th>
            <th>
                subtotale
            </th>
            <th>
                Elimina
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
                Totale:
            </th>
            <th id="order_total">
                €0.00
            </th>
            <th>
                <input id="order_btn" type="button" value="Ordina" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

Comment: You probably need to supply some more information; this is a JavaScript question really as no PHP is involved on actually submitting the form.

You should post your `HTML` code as well so we can see this form. What stage are you at in getting it working? You've said you lack knowledge of how to do this but have written quite a bit of code - what have you tried to do so far and how is it not working the way you'd expect?

Comment: If posting code use the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) website so that we can easily edit your code and see whether your request gets to your `ajax` method call.

Comment: There's also a lot of value in some more consistent formatting across your JavaScript. You have multiple calls to $(function(){}) which could all be placed inside a single function.

Comment: js append item from xml file

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest solution is to use the more accepted way of posting content and put your `input`s inside a `form` element.

This will require you not to use a table but you can easily achieve table appearance with CSS afterwards.

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" class="order">
   <label>Quantity</label> <input id="select_quantity" type="text" /> <br/>
   <label>Select</label> <select id="select_item">
        <option selected="selected">Seleziona un prodotto...</option>
    </select> <br/>
    <input id="add_btn" type="button" value="Aggiungi" />
    <button id="order_btn" value="Ordina" />
</form>
```

Now in your JS:

```
$('form.order').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data=$(this).serialize();
  var url=$(this).attr('action');
  $.post(url, data, function(response){
    // do stuff with response
  });
});
```

The method `$.fn.serialize()` is only available to `form` or `input` elements, and not other containers.

You'd still need to figure out a way to add your inputs as customers added products, but best would be

```
$('button.add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var name=$(this).closest('tr').find('[name="item"]').val();
  var quantity=$(this).closest('tr').find('[name="quantity"]').val();
  $('form.order').append('<input type="hidden" name="item['+name+']" value="'+quantity+'"/>');
});
```

You'll need to check for duplicates etc. but this should get you a good way to it.

Answer (score 0):

here the rest

```
//send order
    $(function() {
        $("#order_btn").click(function() {

        var url = 'http://../order.php';
        var $ordercart = $(this).closest('.order_cart');


        //just a control 4 empty cart
            if ($("#order_cart tr.order_row:last").length == 0)  {
                alert("Nessun prodotto selezionato...");
            } else {            
                //here take the order cart
                var order_cart = $ordercart.find('#order_cart tr.order_row').text();


                //submit the form
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : url,
                    data : {
                        order_cart : order_cart

                    },

                });
                //$.ajax



                alert("Order placed...");



            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

response from consolle:
://../order.php?order_cart=1menu_01Cheeseburger%E2%82%AC3.99%E2%82%AC3.992menu_02Hambuger%E2%82%AC2.99%E2%82%AC5.98